# uiview CGAffineTransform animates backwards

Tags: iphone

I have a `UIView` subclass which I am able to successfully use `UIView` animations on.

This `UIView` also has subviews, which I also want to be able to `UIView` animate.

However, it seems that whenever I create an animation and apply it to the parent view it works fine, but if I apply the animation to the child view it animates backwards.

For example, if I scale my `UIView` parent(self) by a factor of 2 (to double the width and height):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:2];

CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformScale( self.transform, 2, 2  );
self.transform = scaleTransform;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

then this works fine.

But if I do the same on the child:

```
UIView *myObj = [[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:2];

CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformScale( myObj.transform, 2, 2  );
myObj.transform = scaleTransform;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

It doesn't work. What happens visually is that the child view immediately shrinks down and then after the delay scales back up to it's original size.

If I log the transform parameters it looks the same for both parent and child and I have tried setting `CGAffineTransformIdentity`.

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: btw, rotations are working fine, I'm only having an issue with scaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was overriding layoutSubviews and in there I was assigning sizes/positions of the views based upon device orientation which was conflicting.doh!